# Concatenate text and variables to create a path

Tags: python, path

I have the following 3 variables:

```
Year=2022
Month=09
Filename=asd
```

And I need to create the following path:

```
"C:\Documents\2022\09_September\asd.xlsx"
```

How can I create that path including the backslash symbols?

Comment: *Month=09* is syntactically incorrect

Comment: My mistake. The Month variable would be 9 instead of 09.

Answer (score 2):

```
Year=2022
Month='09'
Filename='asd'

path = fr"C:\Documents\{Year}\{Month}_September\{Filename}.xlsx"
```

Comment: also add `r` before the string (`fr"string"`) so the `back slashes` won't be an `escape character`

Answer (score 2):

```py
year=2022
month=9
filename='asd'

path = fr"C:\Documents\{year}\{month.zfill(2)}_September\{filename}.xlsx"
```

Edit:

- format the month in the format `08, 09, 10` instead of `8, 9, 10`
- add `r` to ignore escape characters (`\`)

Comment: just add `r` instead of adding 2 back slashes

Comment: `fr"something"`

Answer (score 1):

When constructing pathnames you should always consider using os.path.join

Something like this:

```
from os.path import join as JOIN

Year=2022
Month=9 # corrected
Filename='asd'

fullpath = JOIN('C:', 'Documents', str(Year), f'{Month:02d}_September', f'{Filename}.xlsx')

print(fullpath)
```

Note how this obviates the need for path separators or raw strings

Comment: How can I add the missing backslash after 'C:'  and before 'Documents'?

Comment: @Aragorn64 The join will do that for you

Comment: When I execute the code above, I get this result:

'C:Documents\2022\09_September\asd.xlsx'

Comment: @Aragorn64 Are you sure? If that happens then it's a Windows peculiarity. Try using r'C:\' as the first argument to JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Using f string

```
path = f"C:\Documents\{Year}\{Month}_September\{Filename}.xlsx"
```

Comment: also add `r` before the string (`fr"string"`) so the `back slashes` won't be an `escape character`

Comment: Without the raw string specifier this will **not** allow access to the intended file due to \a.